# APNS WatchKit. How it works

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit

Please tell us what format notice from Apple Watch. And they generally get a notification at one time as a phone? And if the phone is one format of the notification will have apple watch?
My APNS format for iPhone

```
{
     "aps": {
          "badge": 0,
          "alert": "Your message",
          "sound": "default"
     }
}
```

how to read Apple Watch. And is it possible for him to set up a notification.

I just do not understand. In WatchKit another format, it will process notices for your phone.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Your current format should work fine on the Apple Watch, notifications received on the connected iPhone should go straight to the Watch and display the same data. However you can add a title to your notifications, which is only displayed on the Watch.

To do this, you need to use an alert dictionary instead of a string. Example:

```
{
     "aps": {
          "badge": 0,
          "alert": {
                "title": "This is a title",
                "body": "Your message"
           },
           "sound": "default"
 }
```

Comment: I use the built-in format for the buttons in Watchkit, I have to be inserted into the body for the iPhone my button for iPhone, then I spend a number of characters in JSON - just 256 bytes.

Comment: {
    "aps": {
        "alert": "news",
        "category": "myCategory"
    },
    "WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
                                   {
                                   "title": "READ",
                                   "identifier": "readAction",
                                   }
                                   ],
    "article_id": "20"
  }

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to say is that I'm using buttons in the notification watchkit. This button is found in JSON. When I send notices to the phone and I want to see them on Apple Watch. I have to send messages APNS with integrated buttons for AppleWatch.